# Output returning false when should be true

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to move a folder from one machine to another machine using the script to output the result in a csv file saying it has or not. At the moment i can see that it has by looking at the machine the folder has been moved to but when opening the CSV file it returns false.
Everything goes over fine to another machine but i think there is something in the code that might be off but i'm not sure.

Please see below for code:

```
#>

# This is the file that contains the list of computers you want to send a file to.
# Change this path to point to the txt file. (IE. c:\Script\PClist.txt)
# You can list by host name or IP address.
$computers = gc "C:\Users\stephenstewart\Desktop\Stephen BAT\AssetList.txt"

# This is the FILE you want to copy to the remote/destination computer(s) (IE. c:\file.zip)
$source = "C:\Users\stephenstewart\Desktop\stephen"

# This is the location on the remote/destination computer where you want the file copied to
#(IE.c$\Windows\Temp) use the admin "$"
$dest = "c$\Sun"

# This is the location used to check for Results
$path = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Sun\stephen\Install_me.ps1\"

$results = @()

# There is nothing to change/edit below this line.
Write-Host "Copying Starling folder to all assets listed in AssetList"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
        Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$dest -Recurse
    } else {
        "$computer is not online"
    }
}
Write-Host "Operation Complete"

Write-Host "Preparing Results..."

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if ($path -eq $true) {
        $Output = "True"
    } else {
        $Output = "False"
    }
    $details = @{
        Computer_Name = $computer
        Output        = $Output
    }
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
}

$results | select-object -property Computer_Name, Output | Export-csv 'C:\Users\stephenstewart\Desktop\StephenBAT\stephenResults.csv' -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host "Completed"
```

Comment: Can you update your question to state what it is you're trying to do, instead of just that you get the wrong output?

Comment: I'm trying to move a folder from one machine to another machine using the above script to output the result in a csv file say it has or not. At the moment i can see that it has by looking at the machine itself but when opening the CSV file it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put this into your foreach loop:

```
$path = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Sun\Stephen\Install_me.ps1\"
```

Also I would assign `$true` and `$false` to `$Output` instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Include the test-Path statement in the foreach loop to re-evaluate for each computer:

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $output= Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\Sun\stephen\Install_me.ps1\"

}
```

$output will have a boolean value of $True or $False, this can easily be used in a next statement e.g.

```
if ($output) {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Command #MyCommands}
else 
{#do something else}
```